# Get multiple elements with no XML root JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Consider the test method and test class below that compile and run fine.  If I add another `<TestClass>` element, like this - `<TestClass><x>1</x><y>2</y></TestClass><TestClass><x>1</x><y>2</y></TestClass>` - I get an `UnmarshallException`.

How do I expand the code below to be able to process multiple `<TestClass>` elements?  I don't want to change the XML...I just want to process multiple elements that have no root XML element...

```
    @Test
    public void testJaxbMultipleElementsWithNoRoot() throws Exception{
        String xml = "<TestClass><x>1</x><y>2</y></TestClass>";
        Class xmlResponseClass = TestClass.class;
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(TestClass.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        JAXBElement<TestClass> root = jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml)), TestClass.class);
        TestClass testClass = root.getValue();
        System.out.println(testClass);
    }

    @XmlRootElement(name = "TestClass")
    public static class TestClass {
        private int x;
        private int y;

        @XmlElement(name = "x")
        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public void setX(int x) {
            this.x = x;
        }

        @XmlElement(name = "y")
        public int getY() {
            return y;
        }

        public void setY(int y) {
            this.y = y;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "TestClass{" +
                    "x=" + x +
                    ", y=" + y +
                    '}';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `<TestClass><x>1</x><y>2</y></TestClass><TestClass><x>1</x><y>2</y></TestClass>`

This is not valid XML, as a XML document always has only one single root element.

JAXB can unmarshal only valid XML documents.

Make sure you're only using valid XML documents. Eg. in this case: split them up in 2 XML documents and unmarshal one after the other.

Another solution would be to introduce a new root element which can hold a list of TestClass elements.